# Echos repetidos después de un insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Después de un insert hago que muestre un mensaje pero me salen repetidos, porque es y como lo quito.

Aquí el código

```
$c = ("INSERT INTO usuarios(Tipo,Identificacion,Nombre,NombreUser) VALUES ('$A','$B','$C','$D'");
$result = $conexion->query($c);
if ($result === false) {
   echo 'Exito';
} else {
   echo 'Error';
}
```

Me explicare mejor yo hago un importe con la librería Box Spout y utilizo ese insert, puede que por eso me salga repetido el mensaje?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `$result` , **r** minúscula y en el `if` hace con **R** , no muestra error de variable ?

Comment: La verdad muy raro tu caso, de antemano podrías corregir el `echo 'Exito';;` y probar

Comment: ahh si es que pase mal el codigo, si por eso pregunto aqui porque es raro ese error

Comment: ves dos veces el mismo echo, o los dos echo?

Comment: veo dos veces el mismo echo

Comment: Tendrías que poner el código que rodea a ese fragmento para ver si hay un bucle. Por otro lado, debiera ser error si la respuesta es `false` y viceversa

Comment: Era eso muchas gracias.